# GStreamer RTSP Client increase memory usage gradually in Jetson TX2

Tags: gstreamer

I tested program long times and found it. The memory used by GStreamer rises very slowly.

If RTSP IP Camera is input source, does GStreamer use buffering internally, so does the memory rise to a certain level and keep it constant?

Is it not necessary to change the RTSP-related settings to use the buffer up to a certain size?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstinfo.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <gst/allocators/gstdmabuf.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>

#include <glib.h>
#include <termios.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;


GstElement *pipeline;


int _getch() 
{ 
    int ch; 
    struct termios old; 
    struct termios current; 
    tcgetattr(0, &old); 

    current = old; 
    current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; 
    current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; 

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current); 
    ch = getchar(); 
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old); 

    return ch; 
}


GstFlowReturn new_sample0(GstAppSink *appsink, gpointer data) 
{

    GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(appsink));

    if (sample != NULL)
    {
        GstCaps *caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
        GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);

        int width, height;
        GstStructure* structure = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);
        gst_structure_get_int(structure, "height", &height);
        gst_structure_get_int(structure, "width", &width);
        int size = gst_buffer_get_size(buffer);

        printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, size);

        GstMapInfo map;
        gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

        
        uint8_t *nv12DataBuffer = new uint8_t[size];
        memcpy(nv12DataBuffer, (uint8_t*)map.data, size);
      
        Mat img = Mat(Size(width, height*3/2), CV_8UC1, nv12DataBuffer);
        
        Mat img2;
        cvtColor(img, img2, COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12 );

        imshow("window", img2);
        waitKey(1);

        delete[] nv12DataBuffer;

        gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
        gst_sample_unref (sample);

    }

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}



static void on_pad_added (GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data)
{
    GstElement *source=gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN(pipeline), "rtsp-source");
    GstElement *depay=gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN(pipeline), "depay");

    gst_element_link(source, depay);

    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (source));
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (depay));
}


int main ()
{
    GstElement *source, *depay, *parse, *decoder,  *filter1, *conv, *filter2, *sink;

    gst_init (NULL, NULL);


    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("player");
    source   = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "rtsp-source");
    depay    = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "depay");
    parse    = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "parser");
    decoder  = gst_element_factory_make ("nvv4l2decoder", "decoder"); 
    conv = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "conv"); 
    sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("appsink", "sink");
    filter1 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "video_filter1");
    filter2 = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "video_filter2");

    if (!pipeline || !source || !depay || !parse || !decoder || !filter1 ||!conv || !filter2 || !sink ) {
    printf("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return 1;
    }


    GstCaps    *caps1, *caps2;
    caps1 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)"); 
    caps2 = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw"); 
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter1), "caps", caps1, NULL);
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter2), "caps", caps2, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref (caps1);
    gst_caps_unref (caps2);


    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", "rtsp ip address", NULL);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "emit-signals", true, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "async", false, "sync", false, "max-lateness", 0, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT (source), "latency", 0, NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, depay, parse, decoder, filter1, conv, filter2, sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many (depay, parse, decoder, filter1, conv, filter2, sink, NULL);


    g_signal_connect (source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), NULL);
    if ( g_signal_connect(sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(new_sample0), NULL) <= 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Connects a GCallback function to a signal new-sample" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }


    printf ("Now playing\n");
    
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    printf ("Running...\n");

    while(1)
    {
        int key = _getch();

        if (key=='q') break;
    }

    printf ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    printf ("Deleting pipeline\n");
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
    gst_deinit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does GStreamer use buffering internally, so does the memory rise to a certain level and keep it constant?

Yes and no. Some GStreamer elements *can* use buffering (possibly up to a certain threshold), but not necessarily. For example, an `rtpjitterbuffer` buffers packets, since part of its functionality is to solve packet reordering issues. Some other elements, like the `queue` element, can be used explicitly to do buffering (which for example allows you to decouple the streaming thread on its source and sink pads). Other elements don't, since there is no explicit need for it.

I can see that you use the [`appsink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/appsink.html?gi-language=c) element, which also implicitly buffers incoming data: this is necessary to make sure a pipeline that wants to push a new buffer, doesn't necessarily block if the "new-sample" callback of the previous buffer is still busy. This behaviour can be configured though.

Looking at your code, I see `waitKey(1)` inside your callback, which means your thread will be blocked for a full second before it can go on to the next frame. So if a frame arrives during that second (which will be the case in e.g. a 30Hz stream), it will be queued by appsink. Note that the "max-lateness" property value is ignored, since you're setting the "sync" property to false.

Depending on how you want to deal with this, you have multiple options:

- Set the "max-buffers" property of the appsink, so it only buffers up to a certain threshold, and set the "drop" property to true so that frames will be dropped.
- Don't use a blocking function inside your callback. You could for example queue the newly arrived sample, which you process in a different thread. Note of course, that if you just start queueing in that thread, you'll just have the same issue again.
- Use something else than opencv, since you only use it here to do rendering and color conversion, both of which can also be done in GStreamer (but this depends on your actual use case of course).

Comment: Thanks.  It is very helpful !